# List the API's that are using a given field/property of a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, asp.net-web-api, optimization

Is there any tool/method to list out all the APIs which are using a given field/property of a class in an Asp.Net Web API project?

I can easily list the APIs that will return a given field/property in the *response* by generating Swagger definition (with tools like Swashbuckle ) and by writing some little script to parse it.

but I also want to find the APIs that are using given property to perform any kind of business logic.

Any help/suggestion/alternative would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a way to say, All these API's will be affected if we remove a field from class.

Comment: Can you not search for the property name in your swagger JSON docs?

Comment: @strickt01 By swagger doc I can only get to know the APIs that are using the property in its request or response but It wont give any information about the API that are using the property inside its logic without having the property in either request or response.

Comment: So you're looking for references to that property in your code? In which case most IDEs will be able to tell you where the property is referenced. Failing that, remove the property and try to build the project.

Comment: @strickt01 That's manual process. We have a huge codebase and tracking a reference of property by traveling through all the methods down to the API route will take huge time and manual processes are always prone to human errors so I'm looking for an automated way to do it.